# Create a window through CreateWindow in WinUI3, and place the xaml control before the newly created window

Tags: xaml, winapi, winui-3

In WinUI3, using the CreateWindow method to create a window has been implemented, but this window is placed at the front to obscure the xaml control. Is there any way to have the xaml control in front of the window?

It feels like this is the drawing area created using createwindow
[image]
My own display is incomplete
[image]

```
void SetOpacity(HWND hWnd, int nOpacity)
{
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, (BYTE)(255 * nOpacity / 100), LWA_ALPHA);
}


MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    auto windowNative{ this->try_as<IWindowNative>() };
    HWND hWnd{ 0 };
    windowNative->get_WindowHandle(&hWnd);

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    
    auto sImage = GetFullPathToAsset(L"butterfly.png");
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, &sImage[0], IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    Bitmap bmp(&sImage[0], true);
    Status status = bmp.GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 0), &hBitmap);
    
    HWND hWndChild = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, L"static", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_BITMAP | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE /*SS_REALSIZECONTROL*/, 10, 10, 400, 400, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SetOpacity(hWndChild, 100);
    SendMessage(hWndChild, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
}
```

It is necessary to change the traditional win32 program to WinUI3, the window of CreateWindow, which has very complex algorithm processing. This problem has been bothering me for a long time, no matter how it is implemented, thank you

reference material: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1115740/can-we-use-both-winui3-controls-and-win32-controls

During this period, I reviewed a lot of relevant materials without any gains, and there were few issues related to using CreateWindow in WinUI3

Comment: Might be an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem what are you trying to do in the fist place? use GDI? load bimaps? use transparency? you shouldn't need HWNDs. WinUI3 use Win32 HWND as a host but uses another compositing technology (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/composition) for it's rendering, hacking all this has limited support.

Comment: I'm not trying to display images, I'm just using this as an example

Comment: That's trying to mix technologies that aren't meant to be mixed. WinUI 3 (by default) uses a single `HWND`, primarily for input handling, and to get a "canvas" to render into. Throwing a child window into the mix has unpredictable results, as there are now competing input processing routes and competing rendering technologies. The *real* solution here is to separate the *"complex algorithm processing"* out into a library.